# How pass an object as parameter to Html Unit Driver

Tags: selenium, unit-testing, htmlunit

I have to test a Web page with Html Unit Driver, but I receive an error when i get a page without pass a class object as parameter.

this is the html code:

```
<form name="fund_form" id="fund_form"  th:action="@{/save-fund}"
            th:object="${fund}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id_fund}"> <input
                type="hidden" th:value="${activeId}" th:name="owner" th:id="owner" />
            <input type="hidden" th:value="${0}" th:name="money" th:id="money" />
            <input type="hidden" th:value="${1}" th:name="state" th:id="state" />
            <textarea rows="3" cols="45" th:field="*{subject}" maxlength="135" form="fund_form" required></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" 
name="btn_save_fund" value="Insert NEW FUND!">
```

Here i write a "subject" into a textarea and post it with the button

This is the code of webController:

```
@PostMapping("/save-fund")
public String saveFund(Fund fund, Model model, 
@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {

    fundService.insertNewFund(fund);
    return myFunds(model, user);

}
```

Here i pass the Active User (@ModelAttribute User) as parameter to myFunds method, that reload the page with the funds inserted.

Now I must to test the textarea and the button

This is the code for the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class FundWebControllerIT {

@Autowired
FundRepo fundRepo;

@LocalServerPort
private int port;

private WebDriver driver;
private String baseURL;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    baseURL = "http://localhost:" + port;
    driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    fundRepo.deleteAll();
    fundRepo.flush();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}

//method to test (when I should pass an "user" obj as parameter
@Test
public void testInsertNewFund()  {

    driver.get(baseURL + "/my-funds");

    driver.findElement(By.id("subject")).sendKeys("test fund");
    driver.findElement(By.name("btn_save_fund")).click();

}

}
```

When I run the test I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at
```

com.crowdfunding.controller.ApplicationWebController.myFunds(ApplicationWebController.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.crowdfunding.controller.ApplicationWebController.ActionMyFunds(ApplicationWebController.java:104) ~[classes/:na]

This because the "user" parameter in

```
return myFunds(model, user);
```

is null.

HOW CAN I PASS AN OBJECT AS PARAMETER IN HTML UNIT TEST?

thanks